Is there a specific privacy-policy for the use of Android studio?
I am trying to find the privacy policy that is specific to Android Studio. So far I have only been able to find Googles overall privacy policy, and the latest Gemini privacy policy. However, I have not been able to find a privacy policy that is specific to Android Studio.
Does Android Studio have a specific privacy policy?
Thank you

If you go to https://developer.android.com/studio and click the download button, you first get to see and accept the Terms and Conditions. Section 6 is about privacy.
I'll quote the full thing here for posterity (too lazy to fix the formatting):

Download Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1
Before downloading, you must agree to the following terms and
conditions. Terms and Conditions This is the Android Software
Development Kit License Agreement

Introduction
1.1 The Android Software Development Kit (referred to in the License Agreement as the "SDK" and specifically including the Android system
files, packaged APIs, and Google APIs add-ons) is licensed to you
subject to the terms of the License Agreement. The License Agreement
forms a legally binding contract between you and Google in relation to
your use of the SDK. 1.2 "Android" means the Android software stack
for devices, as made available under the Android Open Source Project,
which is located at the following URL: https://source.android.com/, as
updated from time to time. 1.3 A "compatible implementation" means any
Android device that (i) complies with the Android Compatibility
Definition document, which can be found at the Android compatibility
website (https://source.android.com/compatibility) and which may be
updated from time to time; and (ii) successfully passes the Android
Compatibility Test Suite (CTS). 1.4 "Google" means Google LLC,
organized under the laws of the State of Delaware, USA, and operating
under the laws of the USA with principal place of business at 1600
Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA.
Accepting this License Agreement
2.1 In order to use the SDK, you must first agree to the License Agreement. You may not use the SDK if you do not accept the License
Agreement. 2.2 By clicking to accept and/or using this SDK, you hereby
agree to the terms of the License Agreement. 2.3 You may not use the
SDK and may not accept the License Agreement if you are a person
barred from receiving the SDK under the laws of the United States or
other countries, including the country in which you are resident or
from which you use the SDK. 2.4 If you are agreeing to be bound by the
License Agreement on behalf of your employer or other entity, you
represent and warrant that you have full legal authority to bind your
employer or such entity to the License Agreement. If you do not have
the requisite authority, you may not accept the License Agreement or
use the SDK on behalf of your employer or other entity.
SDK License from Google
3.1 Subject to the terms of the License Agreement, Google grants you a limited, worldwide, royalty-free, non-assignable, non-exclusive, and
non-sublicensable license to use the SDK solely to develop
applications for compatible implementations of Android. 3.2 You may
not use this SDK to develop applications for other platforms
(including non-compatible implementations of Android) or to develop
another SDK. You are of course free to develop applications for other
platforms, including non-compatible implementations of Android,
provided that this SDK is not used for that purpose. 3.3 You agree
that Google or third parties own all legal right, title and interest
in and to the SDK, including any Intellectual Property Rights that
subsist in the SDK. "Intellectual Property Rights" means any and all
rights under patent law, copyright law, trade secret law, trademark
law, and any and all other proprietary rights. Google reserves all
rights not expressly granted to you. 3.4 You may not use the SDK for
any purpose not expressly permitted by the License Agreement. Except
to the extent required by applicable third party licenses, you may not
copy (except for backup purposes), modify, adapt, redistribute,
decompile, reverse engineer, disassemble, or create derivative works
of the SDK or any part of the SDK. 3.5 Use, reproduction and
distribution of components of the SDK licensed under an open source
software license are governed solely by the terms of that open source
software license and not the License Agreement. 3.6 You agree that the
form and nature of the SDK that Google provides may change without
prior notice to you and that future versions of the SDK may be
incompatible with applications developed on previous versions of the
SDK. You agree that Google may stop (permanently or temporarily)
providing the SDK (or any features within the SDK) to you or to users
generally at Google's sole discretion, without prior notice to you.
3.7 Nothing in the License Agreement gives you a right to use any of Google's trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names,
or other distinctive brand features. 3.8 You agree that you will not
remove, obscure, or alter any proprietary rights notices (including
copyright and trademark notices) that may be affixed to or contained
within the SDK.
Use of the SDK by You
4.1 Google agrees that it obtains no right, title or interest from you (or your licensors) under the License Agreement in or to any software
applications that you develop using the SDK, including any
intellectual property rights that subsist in those applications. 4.2
You agree to use the SDK and write applications only for purposes that
are permitted by (a) the License Agreement and (b) any applicable law,
regulation or generally accepted practices or guidelines in the
relevant jurisdictions (including any laws regarding the export of
data or software to and from the United States or other relevant
countries). 4.3 You agree that if you use the SDK to develop
applications for general public users, you will protect the privacy
and legal rights of those users. If the users provide you with user
names, passwords, or other login information or personal information,
you must make the users aware that the information will be available
to your application, and you must provide legally adequate privacy
notice and protection for those users. If your application stores
personal or sensitive information provided by users, it must do so
securely. If the user provides your application with Google Account
information, your application may only use that information to access
the user's Google Account when, and for the limited purposes for
which, the user has given you permission to do so. 4.4 You agree that
you will not engage in any activity with the SDK, including the
development or distribution of an application, that interferes with,
disrupts, damages, or accesses in an unauthorized manner the servers,
networks, or other properties or services of any third party
including, but not limited to, Google or any mobile communications
carrier. 4.5 You agree that you are solely responsible for (and that
Google has no responsibility to you or to any third party for) any
data, content, or resources that you create, transmit or display
through Android and/or applications for Android, and for the
consequences of your actions (including any loss or damage which
Google may suffer) by doing so. 4.6 You agree that you are solely
responsible for (and that Google has no responsibility to you or to
any third party for) any breach of your obligations under the License
Agreement, any applicable third party contract or Terms of Service, or
any applicable law or regulation, and for the consequences (including
any loss or damage which Google or any third party may suffer) of any
such breach.
Your Developer Credentials
5.1 You agree that you are responsible for maintaining the confidentiality of any developer credentials that may be issued to you
by Google or which you may choose yourself and that you will be solely
responsible for all applications that are developed under your
developer credentials.
Privacy and Information
6.1 In order to continually innovate and improve the SDK, Google may collect certain usage statistics from the software including but not
limited to a unique identifier, associated IP address, version number
of the software, and information on which tools and/or services in the
SDK are being used and how they are being used. Before any of this
information is collected, the SDK will notify you and seek your
consent. If you withhold consent, the information will not be
collected. 6.2 The data collected is examined in the aggregate to
improve the SDK and is maintained in accordance with Google's Privacy
Policy, which is located at the following URL:
https://policies.google.com/privacy 6.3 Anonymized and aggregated sets
of the data may be shared with Google partners to improve the SDK.
Third Party Applications
7.1 If you use the SDK to run applications developed by a third party or that access data, content or resources provided by a third party,
you agree that Google is not responsible for those applications, data,
content, or resources. You understand that all data, content or
resources which you may access through such third party applications
are the sole responsibility of the person from which they originated
and that Google is not liable for any loss or damage that you may
experience as a result of the use or access of any of those third
party applications, data, content, or resources. 7.2 You should be
aware the data, content, and resources presented to you through such a
third party application may be protected by intellectual property
rights which are owned by the providers (or by other persons or
companies on their behalf). You may not modify, rent, lease, loan,
sell, distribute or create derivative works based on these data,
content, or resources (either in whole or in part) unless you have
been specifically given permission to do so by the relevant owners.
7.3 You acknowledge that your use of such third party applications, data, content, or resources may be subject to separate terms between
you and the relevant third party. In that case, the License Agreement
does not affect your legal relationship with these third parties.
Using Android APIs
8.1 Google Data APIs 8.1.1 If you use any API to retrieve data from Google, you acknowledge that the data may be protected by intellectual
property rights which are owned by Google or those parties that
provide the data (or by other persons or companies on their behalf).
Your use of any such API may be subject to additional Terms of
Service. You may not modify, rent, lease, loan, sell, distribute or
create derivative works based on this data (either in whole or in
part) unless allowed by the relevant Terms of Service. 8.1.2 If you
use any API to retrieve a user's data from Google, you acknowledge and
agree that you shall retrieve data only with the user's explicit
consent and only when, and for the limited purposes for which, the
user has given you permission to do so. If you use the Android
Recognition Service API, documented at the following URL:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService,
as updated from time to time, you acknowledge that the use of the API
is subject to the Data Processing Addendum for Products where Google
is a Data Processor, which is located at the following URL:
https://privacy.google.com/businesses/gdprprocessorterms/, as updated
from time to time. By clicking to accept, you hereby agree to the
terms of the Data Processing Addendum for Products where Google is a
Data Processor.
Terminating this License Agreement
9.1 The License Agreement will continue to apply until terminated by either you or Google as set out below. 9.2 If you want to terminate
the License Agreement, you may do so by ceasing your use of the SDK
and any relevant developer credentials. 9.3 Google may at any time,
terminate the License Agreement with you if: (A) you have breached any
provision of the License Agreement; or (B) Google is required to do so
by law; or (C) the partner with whom Google offered certain parts of
SDK (such as APIs) to you has terminated its relationship with Google
or ceased to offer certain parts of the SDK to you; or (D) Google
decides to no longer provide the SDK or certain parts of the SDK to
users in the country in which you are resident or from which you use
the service, or the provision of the SDK or certain SDK services to
you by Google is, in Google's sole discretion, no longer commercially
viable. 9.4 When the License Agreement comes to an end, all of the
legal rights, obligations and liabilities that you and Google have
benefited from, been subject to (or which have accrued over time
whilst the License Agreement has been in force) or which are expressed
to continue indefinitely, shall be unaffected by this cessation, and
the provisions of paragraph 14.7 shall continue to apply to such
rights, obligations and liabilities indefinitely.
DISCLAIMER OF WARRANTIES
10.1 YOU EXPRESSLY UNDERSTAND AND AGREE THAT YOUR USE OF THE SDK IS AT YOUR SOLE RISK AND THAT THE SDK IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND "AS AVAILABLE"
WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND FROM GOOGLE. 10.2 YOUR USE OF THE SDK AND
ANY MATERIAL DOWNLOADED OR OTHERWISE OBTAINED THROUGH THE USE OF THE
SDK IS AT YOUR OWN DISCRETION AND RISK AND YOU ARE SOLELY RESPONSIBLE
FOR ANY DAMAGE TO YOUR COMPUTER SYSTEM OR OTHER DEVICE OR LOSS OF DATA
THAT RESULTS FROM SUCH USE. 10.3 GOOGLE FURTHER EXPRESSLY DISCLAIMS
ALL WARRANTIES AND CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, WHETHER EXPRESS OR IMPLIED,
INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES AND CONDITIONS OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
NON-INFRINGEMENT.
LIMITATION OF LIABILITY
11.1 YOU EXPRESSLY UNDERSTAND AND AGREE THAT GOOGLE, ITS SUBSIDIARIES AND AFFILIATES, AND ITS LICENSORS SHALL NOT BE LIABLE TO YOU UNDER ANY
THEORY OF LIABILITY FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
CONSEQUENTIAL OR EXEMPLARY DAMAGES THAT MAY BE INCURRED BY YOU,
INCLUDING ANY LOSS OF DATA, WHETHER OR NOT GOOGLE OR ITS
REPRESENTATIVES HAVE BEEN ADVISED OF OR SHOULD HAVE BEEN AWARE OF THE
POSSIBILITY OF ANY SUCH LOSSES ARISING.
Indemnification
12.1 To the maximum extent permitted by law, you agree to defend, indemnify and hold harmless Google, its affiliates and their
respective directors, officers, employees and agents from and against
any and all claims, actions, suits or proceedings, as well as any and
all losses, liabilities, damages, costs and expenses (including
reasonable attorneys fees) arising out of or accruing from (a) your
use of the SDK, (b) any application you develop on the SDK that
infringes any copyright, trademark, trade secret, trade dress, patent
or other intellectual property right of any person or defames any
person or violates their rights of publicity or privacy, and (c) any
non-compliance by you with the License Agreement.
Changes to the License Agreement
13.1 Google may make changes to the License Agreement as it distributes new versions of the SDK. When these changes are made,
Google will make a new version of the License Agreement available on
the website where the SDK is made available.
General Legal Terms
14.1 The License Agreement constitutes the whole legal agreement between you and Google and governs your use of the SDK (excluding any
services which Google may provide to you under a separate written
agreement), and completely replaces any prior agreements between you
and Google in relation to the SDK. 14.2 You agree that if Google does
not exercise or enforce any legal right or remedy which is contained
in the License Agreement (or which Google has the benefit of under any
applicable law), this will not be taken to be a formal waiver of
Google's rights and that those rights or remedies will still be
available to Google. 14.3 If any court of law, having the jurisdiction
to decide on this matter, rules that any provision of the License
Agreement is invalid, then that provision will be removed from the
License Agreement without affecting the rest of the License Agreement.
The remaining provisions of the License Agreement will continue to be
valid and enforceable. 14.4 You acknowledge and agree that each member
of the group of companies of which Google is the parent shall be third
party beneficiaries to the License Agreement and that such other
companies shall be entitled to directly enforce, and rely upon, any
provision of the License Agreement that confers a benefit on (or
rights in favor of) them. Other than this, no other person or company
shall be third party beneficiaries to the License Agreement. 14.5
EXPORT RESTRICTIONS. THE SDK IS SUBJECT TO UNITED STATES EXPORT LAWS
AND REGULATIONS. YOU MUST COMPLY WITH ALL DOMESTIC AND INTERNATIONAL
EXPORT LAWS AND REGULATIONS THAT APPLY TO THE SDK. THESE LAWS INCLUDE
RESTRICTIONS ON DESTINATIONS, END USERS AND END USE. 14.6 The rights
granted in the License Agreement may not be assigned or transferred by
either you or Google without the prior written approval of the other
party. Neither you nor Google shall be permitted to delegate their
responsibilities or obligations under the License Agreement without
the prior written approval of the other party. 14.7 The License
Agreement, and your relationship with Google under the License
Agreement, shall be governed by the laws of the State of California
without regard to its conflict of laws provisions. You and Google
agree to submit to the exclusive jurisdiction of the courts located
within the county of Santa Clara, California to resolve any legal
matter arising from the License Agreement. Notwithstanding this, you
agree that Google shall still be allowed to apply for injunctive
remedies (or an equivalent type of urgent legal relief) in any
jurisdiction. July 27, 2021


